# Android send image over socket, received blank image

Tags: java, android, sockets

im trying to send image over socket in android using two emulator, log file give me

05-28 13:55:07.349: I/System.out(26763): Receiving...
and i can see the created image from file explorer in data\files\output.jpg but it's blank and it's size =0k

```
   package com.javacodegeeks.android.androidsocketserver;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;

public class Main extends Activity {

    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static Socket clientSocket;
    private static InputStream inputStream;
    private static FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
    private static BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream;
    private static int bufferSize = 3000; // bufferSize temporary hardcoded
    private static int bytesRead;
    private static int totalbytesRead = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        try {
            init();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void init() throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6000); // Server socket

        System.out.println("Server started. Listening to the port 4444");

        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

        byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize]; // create byte array to buffer the
                                            // file

        inputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();

        String filePath = this.getFilesDir().getPath().toString()
                + "/output.jpg";

        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
        // fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);

        System.out.println("Receiving...");

        // following lines read the input slide file byte by byte

        bytesRead = inputStream.read(data,0,data.length); 
        totalbytesRead = bytesRead; 



        do { 
        bytesRead = 
        inputStream.read(data, totalbytesRead, (data.length-totalbytesRead)); 
        if(bytesRead >= 0) totalbytesRead += bytesRead; 
        } while(bytesRead > -1); 

        bufferedOutputStream.write(data, 0 , totalbytesRead); 
        bufferedOutputStream.flush(); 
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
        System.out.println(end); 
        bufferedOutputStream.close(); 
        System.out.println("Sever recieved the file");

    }
}
```

and this is client side

```
    package com.javacodegeeks.android.androidsocketclient;

/*
 * This is a simple Android mobile client
 * This application send any file to a remort server when the 
 * send button is pressed
 * Author by Lak J Comspace
 */

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Transfer extends Activity {

    private Socket client;
    private FileInputStream fileInputStream;
    private BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream;
    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private Button button;
    private TextView text;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_transfer);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); // reference to the send
                                                        // button
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1); // reference to the text
                                                        // view

        // Button press event listener
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    File file = new File("Desktop:\\test.jpg"); // create file
                                                                // instance

                    client = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 5000);

                    byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) file.length()]; // create
                                                                        // a
                                                                        // byte
                                                                        // array
                                                                        // to
                                                                        // file

                    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                    bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(
                            fileInputStream);

                    outputStream = client.getOutputStream();
                    int read_count = 0;
                    while ((read_count = bufferedInputStream.read(mybytearray,
                            0, mybytearray.length)) != -1) {
                        outputStream.write(mybytearray, 0, read_count); // Now
                                                                        // writes
                                                                        // the
                                                                        // correct
                                                                        // amount
                                                                        // of
                                                                        // bytes
                        outputStream.flush();

                    }
                    outputStream.flush();
                    bufferedInputStream.close();
                    outputStream.close();
                    client.close();

                    text.setText("File Sent");

                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: What did you do wrong?

Comment: How can we possibly help you without seeing your code?

Comment: sorry , i add the code now

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first inputStream.read() as there you read the whole filecontents already but throw it away. There is nothing more to read the second time.

Comment: Then explain better what is going on. Add Log statements where you read. Adapt your code. Remove that read statement.

Comment: It should be .write(mybytearray, 0, bytesRead); and .read(mybytearray);

Comment: i update it , hope it's more clear now ,,, thnx alot for your help

Comment: You did not change write() and read(). Log everytime bytesRead. Report the Log here.

Comment: i didnt get what you mean ?

Comment: u mean                     bufferedOutputStream.write(data, 0, bytesRead);
 ?

Comment: Yes of the BufferdInputStream. And no of (data). Reread what I wrote. OMG why did you change that variable name. Now data[] does not have to be filesize. A much smaller buffer would suffice. No need to read the whole file in memory.

Comment: data is the array , i just rename it

Comment: Dit you see your log hiii ? Better log bytesRead, current and filesize. I asked you before to report here that logcat. OMG what is the value of filesize? You dont know that size at forehand so call it buffersize. And so you cannot compare filesize with current. Rename current to totalbytesRead.

Comment: file size initialized to 3000 , ok i renamed it

Comment: i see in logcat this 05-28 14:55:21.997: I/System.out(15085): Server started. Listening to the port 4444
05-28 14:57:22.727: I/System.out(15085): Receiving...

Comment: I give up. You did not change the code as i suggested. You did not add log statements as i suggested. This becomes a never ending story.